# webpack/encore from symfony 4 with socket.io

Tags: symfony, webpack, socket.io, webpack-encore

I tried to use socket.io in my symfony 4 project, still I encounter some issues.
I used **npm install --save socket.io**

then i get this :

```
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.4 (node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.4: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

+ socket.io@2.1.1
added 101 packages in 9.519s
```

But i was thinking "it's ok, it just notice me and it look optionnal".

Still when i used **webpack/encore** i get :

```
PS C:\wamp64\www\PROJETS\my-projet> ./node_modules/.bin/encore dev
Running webpack ...

 ERROR  Failed to compile with 2 errors                                                                         15:41:22

These dependencies were not found:

* fs in ./node_modules/socket.io/lib/index.js
* uws in ./node_modules/engine.io/lib/server.js

To install them, you can run: npm install --save fs uws
```

But install what they want (**fs uws**) don't make it work better when i use **webpack/encore**...
What should i do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`socket.io` is a server side node.js package, you are not supposed to run using webpack. Maybe you are looking for [socket.io-client](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client)? Otherwise, you should use a separate node.js environment.

Comment: ôh ... it's relevant, thanks, i'll try to change some things then i'll be back.

Answer (score 0):

It works, client side can be compiled now. I used **import io from 'socket.io-client';**.

Server side i did it by this way : **let io = require('socket.io')(server);**.

But i'm thinking (server side) that for deployement *webpack/encore* will not compile libraries, then should i add them in sub folder of my Server App ?

Something like this :

`Symfony 4 project
| assets
| bin
| config
| server_app
| | server_app.js
| | lib
| | | here lib for socket.io
| public
| src
| template
...`

(my question may seem stupide)
if I wont add all **node_modules** folder on my server, should I copy paste *socket.io's* folder from **node_modules** to the new folder "**lib**" indicated above ? (all or part)

Else is it a wrong way to deploy it ? (sorry, i'm not familiar with it, I normaly only upload the compiled file from **Encore** ... then when I need to deploy a server side app ...)